# Unintended looping with invalid float

Tags: go

I'm working through the Coursera Go course ... it's pretty good.

In my code below, it works fine when the user correctly a float. But when they enter some random string, it prints the error message and prompt again for each character. Why is that?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func readFloat(title string) float64 {
  var userInput float64

  for {
    fmt.Println("Please enter a float: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%f", &userInput)

    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Wooops! That's not a float\n")
    } else {
      return userInput
    }
  }
}

func main() {
  var f float64

  f = readFloat("acceleration")
    fmt.Printf("You entered: %.04f\n", f)
}
```

```
~/src/coursera/go/course-2-functions-methods/week2 $ go run so.go
Please enter a float:
33.3
You entered: 33.3000
~/src/coursera/go/course-2-functions-methods/week2 $ go run so.go
Please enter a float:
sdf
Wooops! That's not a float
Please enter a float:
Wooops! That's not a float
Please enter a float:
Wooops! That's not a float
Please enter a float:
Wooops! That's not a float
Please enter a float:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if [`fmt.Scanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) encounters an invalid input, it will stop consuming it. E.g. you want to parse a float using `%f`, but if user inputs `sdf`, `fmt.Scanf()` will know it's invalid after the first `s` character, so returns an error and will not consume the rest.

So the next loop iteration begins, it consumes the second character `d`, which is again invalid etc.

If you try to enter `s2` for example, this will become clear:

```
Please enter a float: 
s2
Wooops! That's not a float
Please enter a float: 
You entered: 2.0000
```

First `s` char is invalid, but the next iteration will parse `2`.

One way to "fix" this is to read a whole line as a string, then attempt to parse a float out of the string. For reading a line, use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner), for parsing a float, use [`strconv.ParseFloat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat).

Here's an example how you can do that:

```
func readFloat(title string) float64 {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Printf("Please enter a float for %s: ", title)
        if !scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println("Error readling line")
            return 0 // Should return an error too!
        }

        line := scanner.Text()
        userInput, err := strconv.ParseFloat(line, 64)
        if err == nil {
            return userInput
        }
        fmt.Printf("Wooops! That's not a float\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your for loop is an infinite loop if user enters a wrong value. You should have a `return` statement after your `fmt.Printf("you entered wrong number")`, so that the for loop can exit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ... I want to keep polling until they enter a valid float.